# Samba active directory domain controller, domain name

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller, domain-name

I am new to AD DC, I read through various guidelines on how to set up the server and the domain name system, but I am still confused in the domain
system part.

We decided that our company `example.com` will use the `in.example.com` subdomain for internal purposes. It looks a good idea to use this domain as the base AD domain. In this case the DC DNS name would be some sort of `dc1.in.example.com`.

All the docs I read says that DNS should be up and running before I start provisioning the domain. This is where I start getting confused. The Samba AD DC wants to manage the domain and provide DNS services dynamically updating the zone, so **the authoritative nameserver of the `in.example.com` zone which should be delegated in `example.com` zone should be the DC itself?**

I do not have to configure a PowerDNS or Bind instance for the `in` zone?

In this case, how the `dc1.in.example.com` will resolve before the provisioning?

The other issue is probably related to my confusion. We mostly want to provide internal services in local IP addresses under this subdomain, but we want some for example `wiki.in.example.com` which must be accessible externally from the internet.
**Wouldn't it be a security issue to allow the DC's DNS service to be accessible from the internet** just to be able to resolve the `wiki.in.example.com` name?

Probably I misunderstand something in the concept.
Please shed some light what I am doing wrong!
What would be a typical arrangement to this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

Currently I have a PowerDNS instance on a different, internet-accessible machine, serving the `in.example.com` as a master NS. Albeit the `wiki.in.example.com` should be accessible from outside, it is semantically still classified as internal as it is used internally by the company. This is why I thought at fist that it should go under the internal domain.

Comment: Which docs are you having a look at regarding the setup of the DC? When you set up a brand new domain and promote your first AD DC, you can specify it as the DNS provider in the DC promotion process. It will initially have only the AD DNS zones that are specific to it.

You can then provision additional zones as needed. You *can* integrate other DNS solutions but are not required to in my experience. It might help if you clear up whether or not you have DNS already set up now. If you do and it's authoritative I think you're noting that it needs to delegate this space to the AD DC's IP.

Comment: It is not a good idea to expose your AD DNS to the public. That is correct. You'd instead want to place external zones out on a different DNS solution or perform a 'hidden master' setup if you want to use AD integrated DNS. There are other possible solutions as well.

Does that help? If not perhaps add some more detail about the existing setup as I suggested.

Comment: I added some clarification as an edit, but the current setup is an experiment only yet. I can not list the docs I read, as I read many which come forward by search, among the ones on Microsoft's site about AD domain naming recommendations. The common among the guides that it seems to me that none of them discuss on who will serve the zone, and how to expose some part of it to public with production-ready security.

Comment: By "hidden master" you mean one authoritative nameserver acting as master from outside and one internally in the AD DC? And an out of band synchronization between the two? Seems a little bit complicated to maintain in long term. By the way, how can I delegate this config in the root zone?

Comment: To be honest, I only learned a little bit about that recently myself. This isn't from an AD perspective, but using other technologies but was an article I found on it after it was suggested to me:
https://bryanchain.com/2016/03/24/dns-hidden-master/